# How to plot colored circles knowing X/Y coordinates, radius and a continuous 3rd parameter in R

Tags: r, plot

In a telecommunication project I have a data basis of a list of antennas with their XY coordinates, emission radius and frequencies. I would like to represent with circles the covered area of each antennas, with a specific color depending on the frequency.
Ive been looking for libraries, but I'm very new to R and programmation in general, and I don't find any easy and simple ones. What would you recommend ?
Thank you for any help

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a small amount of example data.   Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, provide some code that you have tried so other do not have to do all the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ggplot2 and ggforce package, like this:

```
  # First generate a sample data
  data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(50),y=rnorm(50),radius = rnorm(50,sd=0.1),freq = factor(1:5,levels=1:5))

  # Load the package
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggforce)
  # Plot
  ggplot(data=data,aes(x0=x,y0=y,col=freq,r=radius)) + geom_circle() +
    coord_fixed()
```